# Fetch all Items in each Category where Item.name = bla: how?

Tags: cakephp

Imagine I have 2 models: Item and Category. Category hasMany Items and Item belongsTo Category.

I would like to obtain an array "reversed" on how cakephp normally return it: Usually I get something like

```
[Item]
    ...some props...
    [Category]
        ...some props...
```

While I want something like:

```
Array
    [0][Category]
        Array
            [0][Item]
               ...some props...
            [1][Item]
    [1][Category]
```

...and so on

How can I obtain this result with **find** method if possible? Otherwise, how to obtain it?

My current model is much more complex but I think I could apply this teory to all my models (I have a Category => Group => Item relationship).

Thanks for suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the title of your question, if the point is to get only Items that are linked to categories named 'bla', you can just call the find() method on the Category model instead of the Item model.

Instead of

```
$this->Item->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Category.name' => 'bla')));
```

do

```
$this->Item->Category->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Category.name' => 'bla')));
```

This way it will first filter the corresponding Categories and then get the linked Items. So you will obtain something like

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [Category] => Array
        (
          [id] => 1
          [name] => bla
          ...
        )
      [Item] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
            (
              [id] => 1
              ...
            )
          [1] => Array
            (
              [id] => 2
              ...
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**EDIT**

With three models linked together, it is a bit more complicated. The only solution I can think of to prevent loading a lot of data is to build a query with INNER JOINs:

```
$categories = $this->Category->find('all', array('fields' => array('Category.id', 'Category.name', 'Item.id', 'Item.name'),
'joins' => array(
    array(  'table' => 'groups',
            'alias' => 'Group',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => 'Group.category_id = Category.id'
        ),
    array(  'table' => 'items',
            'alias' => 'Item',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array('Item.group_id = Group.id', 'Item.name' => 'bla')
        ))));
```

It will return an array like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [Category] => Array
    (
      [id] => 2
      [name] => Shop
    )
    [Item] => Array
    (
      [id] => 1
      [name] => Bla
    )
  )
)
```

**EDIT2**

A last word about the structure of the array you'll get: it is not exactly like you wanted. The Item array is at the same level that the Category array. So you may end up with many pairs of Category-Item for the same Category.

But a simple foreach loop would then allow you to build an array with the exact struture you wish and this query has the advantage to get only what is neccessary from the database.

Comment: I wrote it wrong, sorry. I'm looking for Item.name, not Category.name.

Comment: My mistake too, because after having read you question again, I realize there is a Group model in between that you don't mention in the Array examples, and this is probably important for the answer. So basically, you have categories that contain groups that contain items, and what you want is to get the categories that contain group that contain items called 'bla' ?

Comment: Yes exactly what I want. I didn't mention Group because I thought I could make the query works for Group-> Item and then make it works for Category->Groups, if it's not like that I'll update the question so!

Comment: I edited my answer to give a solution with three models linked together

Comment: Seems like your solution is working gracefully !! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Wait, it seems there is a bug: I think is connected to the fact that you used "bag_id" (which I don't know where it is) and I replaced it with group_id. Is it ok?

Comment: Oups !... I made a test with Category, Bag and Item because I already had a Group model in my test project. I forgot to update this one when I pasted my code... I'll correct the answer.